# How to enable notablescan on MongoDB mongos

Tags: mongodb

My mongoDB cluster is running with one router and several replicasets.  How can I enable the notablescan parameter?  The documentation says it is "Available for mongod only."  I'd like to enable this to force the clients to use an index and prevent slow queries.

Comment: Then you set this on the replicaset members themselves. The router is not relevant here as all it is going to do is direct to the appropriate shard member. If once reaching that shard the operation is prohibited, then the appropriate error will be reported.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this in: /etc/mongodb.conf

```
notablescan = true
```

Comment: is there a way to do this on a per-collection level?

Comment: I think I may have missed the point of your question. AFAIK this is a server setting which spans all collections. The alternative is to be diligent about ensuring all queries are covered by an index.